# Square thumbnails with ImageMagick (convert)?

Tags: imagemagick, image-manipulation

How to create square/cropped thumbnail using ImageMagick ? Cropping like below.

[image: cropping]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is explained in the official ImageMagick documentation under, [“Cut the Thumbnail to Fit”](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#cut):

> An alternative, is rather than pad out the image to fit the specific
>   thumbnail size we want, is to instead cut off the parts of the image
>   that does not fit the final size.
>
> Of course this means you actually lose some parts of the original
>   image, particularly the edges of the image, but the result is a
>   enlarged thumbnail of the center part of the image. This is usually
>   (but not always) the main subject of the image, so it is a practical
>   method of thumbnail creation.
>
> As of IM v6.3.8-3 the special resize option flag '^' was added to make
>   this easier. We just resize using this flag then crop off the parts of
>   the image that overflows the desired size.

And in the context of an example command:

```
convert -define jpeg:size=200x200 hatching_orig.jpg  -thumbnail 100x100^ \
          -gravity center -extent 100x100  cut_to_fit.gif
```

Comment: Possibly... some type of description?

Comment: I love Ignacio's point blank answers :-)

Answer (score 58):

Ignacio linked to the correct documentation, however I'll paste it inline here for convenience:

```
convert -define jpeg:size=200x200 original.jpeg  -thumbnail 100x100^ -gravity center -extent 100x100  thumbnail.jpeg
```

Similarly, the following is for GraphicsMagick:

```
gm convert -size 200x200 original.jpeg -thumbnail 100x100^ -gravity center -extent 100x100 +profile "*" thumbnail.jpeg
```

Explanation:

- `-size 200x200` tells the jpeg decoder we only need this resolution so it can save memory and read the source image faster
- `-thumbnail 100x100^` fast resize making the shortest side 100
- `- gravity center` center the next operation
- `-extent 100x100` apply the image to a 100x100 canvas
- `+profile "*"` do not save any metainfo to the jpeg (making the resulting image smaller)

Comment: When I used it in command line (graphics magick one) I got picture on center, two siders are filled with white. Not the one described in question. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you are using windows you must double the ^ character to escape it. Eg: -thumbnail 100x100^^

Comment: Why not size 100x100 ?

Comment: @HelloWorld: Read "Imagemagick Geometry". Google it, it will be easy find.

Answer (score 11):

That is a simpler way to do it:

The following command resize the smaller side to 100 pixels and crop a 100x100 square. You can add a `-strip` command to reduce file size.

```
convert original.jpg -resize "100^>" -gravity center \ 
                     -crop 100x100+0+0 -strip thumbnail.jpg
```

Unlike others, it isn't trying to save memory. Instead, it does what you want, and no more. Plus, it won't upscale images.

Comment: When adding a late answer to a question with established answers it is helpful to provide enough explanation why your answer offers something unique and new compared to the other answers.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why the others overcomplicated their answers to try to save memory when OP mentions nothing at all about this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using graphicsmagick to generate precisely sized thumbnails but I'm padding the image with a checkerboard instead of cropping the overhang.

```
gm convert -limit Threads 1 -size 320x180 pattern:checkerboard -background transparent -gravity center -resize 320x180 -extent 320x180 original.jpg -flatten -resize 112x65! -interlace Line 1 thumb_112x65.jpg
```

#### Options explained.

```
gm convert

// Single threaded seems faster on smaller files
-limit Threads 1 

// Generate a checkerboard of size 320x180.
// Sets the relative size of the checkerboard squares,
// also sets the desired aspect ratio. In my case (16:9)
-size 320x180 pattern:checkerboard 

// Resize the input image and center it on a transparent layer.
-background transparent -gravity center -resize 320x180 -extent 320x180 orig.jpg

// Merge the layers
-flatten 

// Resize the output to the desired
// The ! causes the aspect ratio to be ignored, fixing any rounding errors.
// (Specify a size with the same aspect ratio as the checkerboard.)
-resize 112x65! 

// Use Progressive JPEG Encoding
-interlace Line 

// Output Image
thumb_112x65.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like:

```
convert -crop 100x100+50+50 input_image.jpg output_image.jpg
```

where `100x100` is the **size** of the final rectangle and `50x50` the **offset**.

Comment: That crop image, but doesn't make thumbnail.

Comment: @marioosh: I didn't understood, you can use `convert -thumbnail 100x100+50+50 input_image.jpg output_image.jpg`, for more info check Igancio Vazquez response for an example or check the [documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#thumbnail)

Answer (score 1):

This command crop to a square and then resize to 150x150

```
convert 824-full.jpg -set option:size '%[fx:min(w,h)]x%[fx:min(w,h)]' xc:none +swap -gravity center -composite -resize 150x150  temp.jpg
```

More options are availble here:
http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#square

Answer (score 0):

To create a batch of thumbnails you also could use `mogrify`

```
mogrify -path ./new/ \
        -resize 733x733^ \
        -gravity Center  \
        -extent 733x733  \
        ./*
```

this converts all .jpgs in the current directory and copies them to the `./new` directory.

Answer (score 0):

The command I use for 100 pixel square thumbnails is (all on one line):
convert input.jpg -thumbnail x200 -resize '200x<' -resize 50% -gravity center -crop 100x100+0+0 +repage -format jpg -quality 91 square.jpg